# Coding vs non-coding DNA length

Tags: genome, phylogenetics, genetics, exon

I am trying to calculate the total exonic length (in bp) in order to see where the coding-noncoding ratio of roughly 1% to 99% comes from.
We know all chromosomes total about 3 billion base pairs. So Is it correct to assume that coding regions would total about 30 million base pairs? I am looking at the numbers in the sources below, but nothing there adds up...

Take numbers from [NCBI annothation](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genome/annotation_euk/Homo_sapiens/108/) for example; specifically

[image: NCBI exon length]

no matter how i count i can't get the expected ratio... What am  doing wrong?

Thank you!

https://www.encodeproject.org/report/?type=Gene&organism.scientific_name=Homo%20sapiens&searchTerm=gene&field=symbol&field=notes

https://archive.vn/20130414235101/http://useast.ensembl.org/Homo_sapiens/Location/Chromosome?r=1

Comment: cross-posted: https://www.biostars.org/p/447675/

Comment: There are a few different answers provided here: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/48110/how-is-the-size-of-a-gene-defined

Comment: Thank you, but this is a different question; my aim is to get the said ratio given the feature numbers, in my case the length of coding vs non-coding regions. The original response helped me by pointing out that i should focus on exons, rather than the entire gene region. So i searched and found some definitive numbers for exon length, and calculated in different combinations, but they still aren't adding up to the 99%-1% ratio. So i'm wondering if i'm missing something else here. Or whether i'm looking at the wrong features entirely.

Comment: They are not adding up because you need exclude non-coding exons (non-CDS) and exclude overlapping features. The discussion I posted shows how to get coding regions. The only difference is that they are trying to get the average length and you need total length.